# Format of "2016-10-22T16:27:54+0000" to convert to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert a string to datetime.

The string is:

```
date_created = "2016-10-22T16:27:54+0000"
```

And I am trying to convert that with:

```
datetime.strptime(date_created, '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
```

but the format does not match.

So, what is the correct format to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%y` matches a year with *two digits*, but your input uses 4 digits. Use `%Y` instead:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_created = "2016-10-22T16:27:54+0000"
>>> datetime.strptime(date_created, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 22, 16, 27, 54)
```

From the [*`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%y`
>   Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   `00, 01, ..., 99`
>
> `%Y`
>   Year with century as a decimal number.
>   `0001, 0002, ..., 2013, 2014, ..., 9998, 9999`

Comment: wow, thanks for saving my time